# Add values to result of query

Tags: mysql

CREATE TABLE `tblstud` (
  `Student_ID` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Middle_Name` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Complete_Address` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CP_No._of_Student` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date_Of_Birth` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Age` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` SET('Male','Female') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Place_Of_Birth` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Grade_Level` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Average_Grade` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Elementary_School_Attended` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ElemSY` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `High_School_Last_Attended` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HighSchoolSY` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name_of_Parent/Guardian` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Occupation` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address_of_Parent/Guardian` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CP_No._of_Parent/Guardian` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Section` VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Student_ID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

I want to write a query that will show the 4th-6th records according to their average grade and marked them Section "A".

I am using mysql and here is my code:

```
UPDATE tblstud SET Section = 'A' 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tblstud ORDER BY Average_Grade DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET)
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yes, What should I do?

Comment: Pls post your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tblstud t1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT *, @rn := @rn + 1 AS row_num 
     FROM tblstud CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) param
     ORDER BY Average_Grade DESC) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
SET t1.Section = 'A'
WHERE t2.row_num BETWEEN 4 AND 6;
```

Comment: would i just copy and paste it on my sql ?

Comment: Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 't1.name' in 'on clause'